# send email to client letting them know the property is expiring soon

Tags: c#, sql

I want to send an email based on an SQL query to find the result set, on 30 days  and 15 days from expiration date ( further alerts on every 7 days ) 
I have a table name property and there is a column Expirationdate.

```
--for 15 days
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Property]
WHERE expirationdate <= DateAdd(day ,15 , GetDate())

--for 30 days
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Property]
WHERE expirationdate <= DateAdd(day ,30 , GetDate())
```

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: What is the best way to deal with what, exactly? Getting the result from SQL? Sending the email? It's not clear what the problem is nor what have you tried so far to solve it

Comment: how to get records of epiration date and once you get the records how to send email to client notifying the property is expriing in 15 or 30 days

Comment: @Tom123 you should edit the question itself to make clear what you actually need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `DateDiff`, the first parameter defines the interval. If you want that to be days, just pass correct value.

More reading here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Example:

```
select * from Property where DATEDIFF(day, Getdate(),expirationdate)<=15
```

I assumed that you have some sort of system to send email with regards to property that is returned with the query, as there was no extra information about it.

—————————

Edit:

If you want to make the full solution, I would suggest following:

1. Create a Console Application that will be connecting to database, and execute above query, and the send the email. There is plenty of help how to do that on the Internet.
2. Schedule that application in Windows Task Scheduler, so it runs every so often and do the work.

Another option you could consider is:

1. Create a SQL Job in SQL Agent that will execute your queries
2. Make Sql sending the email for you.

I hope that helps.

Comment: once you get the records how to automatically send email notifing the client the property is expiring soon

Comment: @Tom123 You cannot. You need to write code to send the email.